# Django3.0.5 and DRF with SWAGGER 2.2.0 problem on API endpoint protected by IsAuthenticated() not showing in swagger

Tags: authentication, django-rest-framework, django-views, swagger

This has become pretty dragged problem in Django-DRF-Swagger API. If my permission class for endpoints are set as (allowany,) then they will all show up but I want to set them as (IsAuthenticated, ) since I want to protect these endpoints. But because of that, none of them actually show up even after I use JWT token to authorize. I have seen so many posts on this subject and none seems to really help.

Comment: Actually DRF-yasg OpenAPI 3.0 version has solved this issue and was able to resolve endpoint no show problem the older Django Rest-Framework-Swagger 2.0 package has. Please refer to documentation for drf-yasg 3.0 for more details.